# Cant find file in the raw folder in android

Tags: java, android

I have a file `dictionary.txt` and I need to get that file from the raw folder so I googled around and found this:

Here's an example:

```
"android.resource:///"+getPackageName()+ "/" + R.raw.dictionary;
```

but it did not work, Any idea?

Edit:

here is what i am doing

```
                for(String line: FileUtils.readLines(file))
                {

                    if(line.toLowerCase().equals(b.toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        valid = true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please post relevant code. "Did not work" tells us nothing.

Comment: It could not find the file

Answer (score 3):

You can get an input stream on a raw resource by using:

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dictionary);
```

EDIT:

From your edit, there really isn't a reason as to why you would specifically need the file rather than just using the input stream available from the `openRawResource(int id)` method...just use an existing java class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dictionary));  

while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
{
     if(scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals(b.toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        valid = true;
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: I need it to be a file.

Comment: Could you explain why/what you're using it for?

Comment: I am using alot of stuff from apache commons io

Comment: You could use the input stream (or file descriptor if you use openRawResourceFd(ID) to copy the file to a file location that you create (and would then, hopefully, know the path to...), but without knowing more specifically what you're trying to do, it's hard to suggest an alternative

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can not create a `File` object directly from the `raw` folder. You need to copy it in your `sdcard` or inside the application`s cache.

you can retrieve the `InputStream` for your file this way

```
    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);

  try {
       int count = 0;
       byte[] bytes = new byte[32768];
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       while ( (count = is.read(bytes,0 32768) > 0) {
           builder.append(new String(bytes, 0, count);
       }

       is.close();
       reqEntity.addPart(new FormBodyPart("file", new StringBody(builder.toString())));
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

EDIT:

to copy it over to internal storage:

```
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "fileName.ext");
try {
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.id._your_id);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buf,0,len);
        }

        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {}
```

Now you have a `File` that you can access anywhere you need it.

Comment: I am sorry but i am new to android and don't know how that would help:(

Comment: what do you want to use it for?

Comment: Stuff from apache commons io

Comment: @Welsar55 we can help you better, if you post the code for your exact requirement, like the function you need to pass it to, may be it has some other overload, or see the edit on my answer for creating a file in internal storage

Comment: Added what i am doing

Answer (score 1):

Place the file in the `assets` folder and open it like this

```
getResources().getAssets().open("dictionary.txt");
```